# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="v-button-caption">...</span>

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have created one funcion called.   def Handel_ErrorToHigh():
And i am trying to give that fuction call in the if statement. But while doing so its giving me above error: Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?  Many Thanks
Below is my new code :

```
if Currency[0] =='kr':
    print("Hello, I am printing €, as I am in Euro til")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//div[@class='v-customcomponent v-customcomponent-gk-action-bar gk-action-bar v-customcomponent-portal-menu-actionbar portal-menu-actionbar']//Span[contains(text(),'Drawer')]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//div[@Class='v-tree-node-caption']//Span[contains(text(),'Drawer Accounts')]").click()
    driver.switch_to.frame(1)
    print("I am inside frame")
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//span[text()='Account']"))).click()
    print("I have cliked on Account")
    current_loan = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Current Loan/Change Amount')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'horizontallayout')]/../../following-sibling::div/descendant::input").get_attribute('value')
    print(current_loan)
    new_loan = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right']")))
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='v-textfield v-textfield-text-align-right text-align-right']")))
    val = "2000000"
    new_loan.send_keys(val)
    actual_val = int(val)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Post')]"))).click()

    def Handel_ErrorToHigh():
        const_val = 100
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Post')]"))).click()
        #post.click()
        i = 0
        while True :
            try:
                if(len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Close']"))) > 0:
                    print("Alert is visible" , i)
                    i  = i + 1
                    print(i)
                    close_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Close')]")))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close_btn)
                    new_loan.clear()
                    keys_to_send = actual_val - const_val
                    new_loan.send_keys(str(keys_to_send))
                    post_btn=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Post')]")))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", post_btn)
                    const_val = const_val  + 10
                    if const_val >= 1000:
                        break
                    else:
                        print('Post must have worked')
                        break
            except:
                print('Something went wrong in code')
                break

    Error_length = []
    Error_length = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Close']"))
    if Error_length > 0:
        Handel_ErrorToHigh()
    else:
        print("I did not go to IF")
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="v-button-caption">...</span> is not clickable at point (69, 57). Other element would receive the click: <div class="v-window-modalitycurtain" style="z-index: 10000;"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which of the clicks causing this error,  I guess it comes here:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Close')]"))).click()
```

If so, try using JavaScript executor click instead, like this:

```
close_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Close')]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close_btn)
```

In case other click causing this error - do the same change there.
Instead of clicking it with selenium driver do this with JavaScript executor
**UPD**
You can try 2 more approaches:

```
close_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Close')]")))
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element ).click(element ).perform()
```

or

```
close_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Close')]")))
time.sleep(1)
close_btn.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for answring .. I chnaged code like this :

Comment: close_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Close')]")))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close_btn)
                    new_loan.clear()
                    keys_to_send = actual_val - const_val
                    new_loan.send_keys(str(keys_to_send))
                    post_btn=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Post')]")))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", post_btn)

Comment: Please update the question, your code is not really readable here

Comment: So changed both Post and close, also note that this while lop was working beofore . Now i just wrapped this in a function and called it and this is now giving error

Comment: Same error :   File "C:\Users\kenaik\PycharmProjects\gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="v-button-caption">...</span> is not clickable at point (69, 57). Other element would receive the click: <div class="v-window-modalitycurtain" style="z-index: 10000;"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)

Comment: for the same command or for some other now?

Comment: Also, instead of what I wrote in the answer, try after `close_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Close')]")))
` giving a short delay `time.sleep(2)` and after that do `close_btn.click()`

Comment: Sure, ill try that , but I wonder this was working before, nothinh has chnaged only wrapping into funstion and calling it

Comment: I have updated the answer, added 2 more ways, this and 1 more

Comment: close_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Close')]")))
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element ).click(element ).perform()